# How to change template for multiple items

Tags: media-library, templates, powershell

There are many PDF files in our project that are manually added to the media library.

I see that some of them have the template - `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/Pdf`
and some others - `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Pdf`

1. Why does this happen. I'm sure the author would not select any settings to have it uploaded as 'Versioned'.And this happend with image files too.
2. I would like to change all `versioned pdf` to `unversioned pdf`.

When I try this power shell script, it throws an error:

```
$master = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master");
$entryTemplate = $master.Templates["/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Pdf"];
cd master:"\media library\Files\Test";
Get-ChildItem -recurse | ForEach-Object { if ($_.TemplateName -eq "Pdf") { $_.ChangeTemplate($entryTemplate) } };
```

> Exception calling "ChangeTemplate" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: template" At line:8 char:76
>   + ...  ($*.TemplateName -eq "Pdf") { $*.ChangeTemplate($entryTemplate) } };
>   +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
>
> Exception calling "ChangeTemplate" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: template" At line:8 char:76
>   + ...  ($*.TemplateName -eq "Pdf") { $*.ChangeTemplate($entryTemplate) } };
>   +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Using Sitecore 8.2 update 3

Comment: have you tried adding `"` characters around `"master:\media library\files\Test"`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I just tried and it threw a new exception. Updated in question. Please have a look.

Comment: Try `$entryTemplate = $master.Templates["System/Media/Unversioned/Pdf"];`

Comment: @MarekMusielak That worked!!! Thank you so much. Could you please post it so that i can mark it as an answer. I would also appreciate if you could mention the reason for that path and also why this issue occurs. Thanks again.

Comment: Comments converted into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, wrap your media library test files path with `"` characters.

Then instead of passing the whole path to `$master.Templates`:

```
$master.Templates["/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Pdf"];
```

use only template specific subpath

```
$master.Templates["System/Media/Unversioned/Pdf"];
```